# PHP script that connect SQL with Flash

Tags: php

```
<?

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "adaptasi";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT isi FROM materi WHERE judul = morfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "0 results";

$conn->close();
?>
```

and this the action script

```
var filepath:String;

if (_url.indexOf("http") != 0) filepath = "http://localhost/adaptasi/";
else filepath = "../scripts/";

var send_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var result_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

result_lv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean):Void {
   TextIsi1.text = result_lv;
}

send_lv.sendAndLoad(filepath + "morfologi.php", result_lv, "GET");
```

I have error result in text field in Flash.
I build flash that connect that just show data from MySQL database.
Need your help, and thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Flash be integrated with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590199/can-flash-be-integrated-with-sql)

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled? Is `morfo` a string? If so that should be quoted.

Comment: I have qouted but it's not work